Avoid running python chunk within Rmarkdown document
I want a chunk of python code to be reproduced but not run in my markdown document.
I have tried

{python, eval=FALSE} print("Hello Python!") 

but it actually runs the code.
I prefer not to use simply the "```" because I want to use code folding.

Could you please share more code of your document so we can reproduce it?
